# java program using ProcessBuilder working in command prompt but not in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to execute an .jar file using java code and I have used ProcessBuilder for that. I have placed the java file and the jar file I need to execute in the same folder and tried executing my code it worked :) . But, Now I have created a project in eclipse and I have configured the build path for that jar and I tried executing the java file but I am not abel to do so :(

My java file : Test.java

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;

 public class Test
 {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
    {
            try
            {
                    String url="some error url";
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar","myjarname.jar","attr 1","attr 2","attr 3");
                    Process p = pb.start();
                    System.out.println(p.getInputStream().read());

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            if(line.contains("https://"))
                            {
                                    url=line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("https")+0);
                                    System.out.println(url);
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println(p.getErrorStream().read());

                    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? It would help a lot if you could add that do your post

Comment: probably eclipse is trying to open it from folder inside eclipse work space folder where .class exist. error message will tell you exact problem

Comment: I din't get any error but at the same time I am un abel to get the output. But it's done now I have placed the jar file in the directory at which my project was created then it worked.  thank you :)